# Cognito SMS Auth to SNS in a different region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-sns

I have a Cognito set up in eu-central-1 and now I need SMS MFA to be activated in Cognito. AWS docs tells me that Cognito will send SMS through AWS SNS however, the SNS in region eu-central-1 does not have SMS availability.

I now have an SNS in a different region (us-east-1) with an SMS limit of $1000 but how can I connect the Cognito in eu-central-1 to send sms through SNS in us-east-1? Is it even possible or would I have to move my Cognito to us-east-1?

The Cognito role has the relevant permission to access/publish through SNS.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Cognito Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-email-phone-verification.html):

> SMS messages from Amazon Cognito user pools are routed through Amazon SNS in the same region unless noted in the following table.

| Amazon Cognito Region | Supported SNS Regions |
| --- | --- |
| US East (Ohio) us-east-2 | us-east-1 |
| Asia Pacific (Mumbai) ap-south-1 | ap-southeast-1 |
| Asia Pacific (Seoul) ap-northeast-2 | ap-notheast-1 |
| Canada(Central) ca-central-1 | us-east-1 |
| Europe (Frankfurt) eu-central-1 | eu-west-1 |
| Europe (London) eu-west-2 | eu-west-1 |

Check [the docs for the latest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-email-phone-verification.html) but `eu-central-1` gets routed through `eu-west-1` at the time I'm writing this.  I came across this with my deployment in `us-east-2` which gets routed through `us-east-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to connect a aws-cognito-userpool from `eu-central-1` with aws-sns `Text messaging (SMS)` in `eu-west-1`. They don't have to be in the same region.

However aws now offers sending sms via `eu-central-1` and explicitly asks to maintain isolation of regions.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/amazon-cognito-launches-support-for-in-region-integration-with-amazon-ses-and-amazon-sns/

1. switch to the new interface (displayed at top: `The new design for Cognito User Pools console is now available. Try out the new interface`)
2. select user pool
3. go to tab `Messaging`
4. Section `SMS` and `Edit`
5. select region from dropdown at section `SNS Region`

Answer (score -1):

There is a screen to configure this for your AWS Cognito.

1. Navigate to AWS Cognito -> Manage user pool
2. Select the User Pool where notification has to be configured.
3. Navigate to the section 'Message Customizations'
4. Choose the SES Region where it is **configured** in your account and fill the remaining fields.
5. In the option 'Do you want to send emails through your Amazon SES Configuration?' choose 'Yes - Use Amazon SES'.
6. Go to bottom and save the changes (make necessary changes in other fields according to your requirement.)

Comment: But isn't that just for email? because it requires me to verify and add a "From" email. I'm not interested in email verification, just SMS.

Comment: SMS service is dependent on the Telecom service provider in specific country. So, please check the list https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-supported-regions-countries.html to see whether your country is supported.

Comment: SMS is not supported in eu-central-1 so that service cannot be used.

Comment: Yes which is why I moved SNS to us-east-1. Now my question is that will I have to move Cognito to that region as well or will the Cognito in eu-central-1 be able to communicate with SNS in us-east-1?

Comment: Yes, you can move the region for Cognito. However, that decision should be taken only after analysing factors like network connectivity to on-prem (if required), region of expected users for the application, cost, etc.